# How to set the width of Semantic UI dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net, semantic-ui

How can I set the width of the Semantic UI Search Selection drop down? I need to set the width of Semantic UI Search selection dropdown to the longest element in the dropdown. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I used a fixed-size wrapper combined with a fluid (expands to fit size of parent) dropdown nested inside of it

```html
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <div class="ui fluid dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="country">
    <div class="default text">My Dropdown Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also add `display:inline-block;` to preserve the standard display setting

Answer (score 7):

Try setting the `min-width` instead of setting the `width`. The default is a `min-width` of `14em`, so you'll need to override that if you wish to have a smaller width.

Example:

```
.ui.dropdown.search{
     min-width: /*smaller width here*/;
}
```

Comment: That information was helpful to get the auto width (React)
.ui.selection.dropdown {
  min-width: auto !important;
}

Comment: Damn Alex... you saved the day.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the 'compact' attribute as shown below.  However it only adjusts the width based on what is selected.

```
<div class="ui compact selection dropdown">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="text">Compact</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```